# Angular9 ng-serve access outside localhost

Tags: node.js, angular, network-programming, angular9, serve

Being able to serve my application to a couple of friends over a VPN network.

1. Configuration 1:

   - OS:Slackware x64
   - Node:13.13.0 --- built from source.
   - Npm: 6.14.4
   - ng: 9.1.1
   - ts: 3.8.3. (although the project uses 3.7.5)
2. Configuration 2:

   - OS: Win10 64bit
   - Node:12.16.2 -- next,next,finish.
   - Npm: 6.14.4 (possibly?)
   - ng: 9.1.1
   - ts: 3.8.3. (although the project uses 3.7.5)

Test devices:

- Android smartphone (v5 series)
- Windows 8.1 x64
- Windows 10 x64 All three devices are connected to the same VPN my Configuration 1 and 
  Configuration 2 are connected to
- Iphone on its' own mobile internet connection, connected through VPN to me
- Windows 7 machine from another location, also connected only through the VPN

---

Results with Configuration 2:

when using ng serve --host vpn.address.x.y --port custom --disable-host-check

It works flawlessly for all three devices

Results with Configuration 1:

when using ng serve --host vpn.address.x.y --port custom --disable-host-check

Other than running locally, I can run it successfully from test device 1 (Android smartphone), test device 2 (Win8.1) and test device 4 (Iphone)

- but on the Win10 machine, I get a "Loading failed for module with source.... and an error :12:1
- On test device 5(Win7) I get the same issue as on Win10
- What I already tried:

  1. Building v12.16.2 version on the Configuration 1 (linux)
  2. Just unzipping the node binaries for 12.16.2

Both attempts produced the same result as the current 13.13.0 node I compiled from source, so I hope it's not related to node.

I ALSO tried:

- passing --host 0.0.0.0
- passing --host my_local_IP
- passing --host my_external_IP
- passing --port 4200
- passing --port 8080
- passing --port 49000+ (random numbers, really)

These adjustments changed nothing for either Configuration 1 nor Configuration 2 (on 1, it didn't change for the better, on 2 it didn't change for the worse)

Changing browsers didn't change anything for either configuration either. If it works, it works on all browsers on the target test device. If it doesn't, it doesn't work on any browser on the target test device.

I'm posting this as an angular question since I tested a simple with-slackware-shipped apache webserver on the problematic Win10 machine and that webserver is accessible from that Win10 machine.
(The famous "It works!" message is shown)

UPDATE:
I tested using

> ng build
>
> ng build --prod

and then serving the output folder of that command as the directory from which my httpd should serve from.
Results are consistent: If it works otherwise, it works with this as well. If not, then not.

I'm evermore steering away from a possible angular-related connectivity issue to perhaps an issue with windows, perhaps? Only Windows (7 and 10, although not 8.1) failed, while iOS and Android did not?

Any insight or a nudge in any direction will be appreciated. I possibly overlooked something.

**Please note, both configurations are on the same laptop machine, so there are no hardware discrepancies, only software.**